# Forcing users to write input in a specific format

Tags: c, input, string-formatting, scanf

i'm making a program in C. that keeps track of items in a warehouse.

and i want to force the user to include at least one number!
example dvd1, dvd2. hello1, hello20

is there a way to do this?
at this moment i am using scanf.

and i want the product code to have the requirement format of  xx-xxx-xxx were x are numbers.

i'm using scanf ( %[0-9-]s

Mvh Anton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf doesn't work like that, it doesn't have in-depth validation.

You need to read the input into a char array, then loop through each character and see if it is a digit.

Something like this (untested):

```
char buffer[1000];
int i = 0, hasDigit = 0;

scanf("%s", buffer);
while (i < sizeof(buffer) && buffer[i] != 0 && !hasDigit)
{
  hasDigit = isdigit(buffer[i]);
  i++;
}

// if hasDigit is 0, there are no digits
```

Note: scanf isn't great, since if you enter more characters than fit in the buffer it can cause a buffer overflow. It is better to use fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

Answer (score 0):

Read the input and you can iterate through as in [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213827/how-to-iterate-over-a-string-in-c). You can check to see if `chars` match the input you want pretty easily from that point on.