# How to access separate characters in a string?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a string like this:

```
char* hello = "Hello, world!";
```

And I have to loop through every character in this string. I tried these, but they either give me compile error, or access violation, or just never leave loop:

```
for( char* p = hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);

for( char* p = &hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);

for( char* p = *hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);

for( char* p = hello; *p!=0; *p++ ) printf("%x\n", *p);
```

I don't really understand how pointers work in C, I'm just placing asterisk randomly until it works, and in this case it doesn't.

I don't use `strlen` like that other question.

Comment: If you don't understand pointers, please read a tutorial. Stack Overflow cannot replace a tutorial.

Comment: Then maybe you need to read-up on pointers first: http://www.praxagora.com/doc_model/understanding_c_pointers_1.0.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a string in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213827/how-to-iterate-over-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @FUZxxl maybe you know about a good collection of examples of working with pointers?

Comment: @PeretFinctor Only in German, sorry. But [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E) might be somewhat enlighting.

Comment: regarding this line: `for( char* p = hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);`  it is 'almost' correct.  1) the pointer `p` will not be 0 until it overflows,  However, where it points will contain a '\0' at the end of the string.  2) the 'p' in the printf() statement is a pointer to 'the rest of' the string.  I suspect you only want to print a single byte, in hex.  Suggest: `for( char* p = hello; *p; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p[0]);`  where '*p' means where p points so will exit the for loop when at the NUL byte at the end of the string.  Where 'p[0]' is the single byte currently pointed at by 'p'

Comment: Your fourth option is correct if you're on an ASCII system (likely) , you will get the ascii codes of each character in the string printed.

Comment: @user3629249 `p` will never compare equal to zero (Unless the program has already triggered undefined behaviour, of course)

Comment: @user3629249 I was responding to your claim "the pointer p will not be 0 until it overflows"

Comment: @M.M,  'p' is a pointer, there are no negative pointers (a negative value will just wrap around memory as if it were a very large positive value % max memory address.)

Comment: The stuff you put in brackets isn't true . Maybe you describe some manifestation of undefined behaviour on some particular system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them.

The answer is : `for( char* p = hello; *p !=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", *p);`

char *p = hello; // p is pointing on the first case of hello, it's exactly the same as `char *p = &hello[0];`

`if(*p == 0)` // check if *p == '\0' ('\0' == 0 in ASCII, which means end of string). *p is the value of the adress pointed per p.

'p++' // increase p of sizeof(char) ( so it's += 1). With that you are on the adresse of hello[1] then hello[2] etc...

Comment: well, not quite.   in the second parameter of the 'for()' statement, this is comparing a single byte '\0' to the (4 or 8 bytes) integer 0.   in the 'printf()' statement the 'p' is the address contained in 'p'   However a pointer is properly printed with a '%p' not a '%x'; but the OP wants to print the char pointed to by 'p' in a hex format, so it should be: 'p[0]'

Comment: @user3629249 What do you know about implicit conversions?

Comment: And yes, this should be `printf("%c\n", c);` to print the characters (as opposed to the address of each character)

Comment: I know a massive lot about implicit conversions.  I also know that the OP doesn't know, so the suggest answer is misleading the OP.

Comment: %x = hexadecimal representation. Failed, forgot to put *p in the printf.

Comment: `printf("%x\n", *p);` will cause undefined behaviour if any of the characters in the string have negative character codes

Comment: he is using the 1st ASCII table, good luck to find a negative value.

Comment: `%x` will not print the address of each character, just the hex representation of it. I'm sure that's what you meant, but just being explicitly clear.

Answer (score 5):

`p` is a pointer to `char`. Therefore, dereferencing it with `*p` yields
a `char`.

Adding 1 to `p` moves it to the next character in whatever string you’re
traversing. Adding 1 to `*p` adds one to the character `p` is pointing
to.

Let’s go through each of your tries and see what’s wrong with it.

```
char* hello = "Hello, world!";
```

The common part: `hello` is a pointer to `char`, and it is pointing to a
constant string that the compiler will embed somewhere in the object
file. Note that such a string should not be changed; you will often get
an error for doing so.

If you want a string you can change, `char hello[] = "Hello, world!";`
works; this creates a buffer as a local variable that can be freely
manipulated.

```
for( char* p = hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);
```

Here, you correctly point `p` at the first character of `hello`.
However, you then look for the end of the string by comparing `p` to
zero. `p` is a pointer, and 0 as a pointer means a NULL pointer.

```
for( char* p = &hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);
```

Here, you point `p` at the address of `hello`, meaning wherever the
process is storing the pointer known as `hello`. Dereferencing this will
give you `hello`, not what it points to.

```
for( char* p = *hello; p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", p);
```

Here, you dereference `hello`, giving a `char` with a value of `H`.
Assigning this to `p` is a type mismatch and semantically incorrect as
well.

```
for( char* p = hello; *p!=0; *p++ ) printf("%x\n", *p);
```

Here, at last, you correctly compare what `p` points to, to zero. 
<s>However, you also increment `*p` instead of `p`, which is incorrect,
and also (as mentioned above) will cause problems with a constant string
such as this one.</s>
`*p++` will increment `p` as well, returning what `p` pointed to before
the increment, which is moot since it isn’t used.

<s>One other thing: do you want to print the value of the pointer `p`, or
the `char` it’s pointing to? The first three print the pointer
correctly. The last one uses `%x` to print the `char`. Not sure what
that will do, but it won’t be correct.</s>

Since you used `%x`, I assume you want to print the character itself in
hex? That would be `printf("%x\n", *p);` as in the last one. However, I
would recommend `%02x` to get a constant width with zero-padding.

Assuming you want to print the character, here’s a correct version:

```
for( char* p = hello; *p!=0; p++ ) printf("%x\n", *p);
```

Or, since `0` is false, we can say more briefly and idiomatically:

```
for( char* p = hello; *p; p++ ) printf("%x\n", *p);
```

Comment: D'oh. Too rusty in C I guess.