# How to separate a number from a letter stored in a string

Tags: c, string

I can seem to figure out how to seperate a letter identifier from a number in a string. For example trying to seperate Q10 into two parts Q and 10. Any help is greatly appericated Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “separate”? Is the letter always the first character in the string and the rest is the number? What do you want to do with the number, just print it out, or actually do math to it?

Comment: Have you tried something? Post it.

Comment: only a single letter and 2 digits or any number of letters and digits or?

Comment: So I am trying to comapre one identifer with another. I.e Q10 with E2, it will always be in the order, Letter then number with a max of two digits in the number.

Comment: assuming the you have a char* to hte start of the string sptr, look at atoi(++sptr)  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are suggestions to use some functions from other libraries but you can do it yourself.

First of all you need to iterate over a whole string char by char. To do that check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213827/how-to-iterate-over-a-string-in-c) question.

Now we know how to do this we need to know what to do with given char and see is it number or letter or something else.

Each `char` has it's representing value from `ascii` table.

If for example we have `char a = '1'` in `ascii` code it is represented as `49`.

So now we can do something like this:

```
char test = '5';

if(test >= 48 && test <= 57) //These represents numbers in ascii
{
    // Do something since our char is number
}
else if(test >= 65 && test <= 90) // These represents Higher Up Letters
{
    // Do something with higher up letter
}
else if(test >= 97 && test <= 122) // These represents lower case letters
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // It is not number, nor lower case letter, nor higher case letter
}
```

Now if we implement this in our loop you can do whatever you want, maybe store all number in one string and characters in other, or add them up or something else, it is up to you.

Comment: This assumes that the character set is ASCII. This is not always the case. The truly portable way to test for a digit in a string is to use `isdigit`.

Comment: @GovindParmar You are right and i will mention that but since this is basic question i assume he is beginner and wanted to make him understand it more in deep than just using some built in function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `isdigit` in `<ctype.h>` to determine when to stop incrementing a pointer to the string:

```
char *p = str;
while(*p)
{
    if(isdigit(*p)) break;
    p++;
}
puts(p);
```

If there is no number in `str` , the `puts` line will output a newline and nothing else.