# How can I make a char* point to a char[]?

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering if there is a way to make `char*` point to the contents of a `char` array so that I can modify the `char*` across functions.

For example

```
void toup(char* c) {
  char array[sizeof(c)];
  for (int x;x<strlen(c);x++){
    array[x]=toupper(c[x]);
  }
}

int main(){
  char *c="Hello";
  toup(c);
}
```

Trying to make the `array = char*` does not seem to work. Is it possible to make the char* point to the char array?

Comment: because rhs is a const char pointer.

Comment: The answers are different in c and c++. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: `for (int x;x<strlen(c);x++){` `x` is uninitialized. Did you mean `int x = 0`?

Comment: Please tag only one language. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Extending on above comment: `for (int x = 0;x<strlen(c);x++)` could get expensive. Might be better to `for (char * p = c; *p !='\0'; p++)` and then operate on `*p`

Comment: Side note: See [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for a built-in function for performing operations like this.

Comment: regarding: `char array[sizeof(c)]`  this defines an array of (depending on the underlying hardware (16/32/64 bytes) the number of bytes in a pointer.  This is probably NOT what you want

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to make the char* point to the char array?

Yes. Instead of:

```
int main(){
  char *c="Hello";
  toup(c);
}
```

Use:

```
int main(){
  char c[] = "Hello";
  toup(c);
}
```

`char *c = "Hello";` makes the string const and usually puts the string in a const data section. `char c[] = "Hello";` provides the mutable string you want.

Also see [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20944784/608639).

---

Also see [Blaze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620668/how-can-i-make-a-char-point-to-a-char/57620701#comment101695496_57620668):

> `for (int x;x<strlen(c);x++)` x is uninitialized. Did you mean int `x = 0`?

---

Two  other caveats...

```
void toup(char* c) {
  char array[sizeof(c)];
  for (int x;x<strlen(c);x++){
    array[x]=toupper(c[x]);
  }
}
```

First, `toup` is modifying a local array. It is not visible outside the function.

Second, `sizeof(c)` yields either 4 or 8 since it is taking the size of the pointer. That means the declaration is either `char array[4];` on 32-bit machines, or `char array[8];` on 64-bit machines.

`array[x]=toupper(c[x]);` should segfault when the length of string `c` is larger then the pointer.

You should probably do something like:

```
void toup(char* c) {
  for (size_t x=0;x<strlen(c);x++){
    c[x]=toupper(c[x]);
  }
}
```

A similar question is at [How to iterate over a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3213827/608639) Also see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/608639)

Answer (score 3):

No need for temporary buffer `array` - you already have stream of characters in input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void toup(char* c) {
  for (char * it = c; *it !='\0'; it++){
    *it = toupper(*it);
  }
}

int main(){
  char c[] = "Hello";
  toup(c);
  printf("%s\n",c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `toup` function has problems:

1. `char array[sizeof(c)]` here `sizeof(c)` is the size of a pointer, not the string.
2. `int x` is not initialized in the for loop.
3. `x < strlen(c)` is very very very inefficient. You are calculating the length every iteration and `strlen` is an expensive function.

And in the main function, `char *c="Hello";` is not valid C++. You meant `char c[] = "Hello"`

Here's is one way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
  char str[] = "Hello World";
  std::for_each(std::begin(str), std::end(str),
    [](char& c) { c = std::toupper((unsigned char)c); });
  std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Since you are using C++11 (implied by `std::begin`) , I'd write that for_each as `for (char &c: str) { c = std::toupper((unsigned char)c); }`.  Unless you want to iterate over part of a container, `for_each` is not very useful now.

Comment: @MartinBonner I think it is sensible to prefer STL algorithms over hand-rolled loops. They may be optimized and are less error-prone. Also, if needed, OP can replace `std::for_each` with something like `std::transform` very easily.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  Algorithms are one of the ugliest parts of the standard.  You can do some amazingly clever things with them - but doing so results in code which is almost impossible to read.  I don't care about optimization (and the compiler will generate the same assembler in both cases anyway).

Comment: @Ayxan If you don't use a specialized algorithm, you should prefer range-based for loop over `std::for_each`. It essentially does the same thing but it easier to read (less noise) *(and also a bit less error prone as you specify the container once and don't explicitly specify begin and end.)*

Answer (score -1):

To get a pointer to a char array:

```
char *ptr = array;
```

To then use values from it (i.e. printf)

```
printf(“%c\n”,*(ptr + i));
```

make sure to dereference ptr by using `*`

Comment: Hmm... your use of double quotes - `“` and `”` - will surely cause a compile failure. I don't know of any C compilers that accept them.

Comment: @jww ah I was writing on my phone, it made it into those quotes.