# Iterate through a character in C

Tags: c, string, character

I am from the Fortran community so forgive for asking such a simple question.

I have the following:

```
 char temp_line[250];
  char *line;

  // read in a file and get first line 
    line = fgets(temp_line, 250, fp) ; 

    // Now I want to iterate through each character in line 
    // my line in reality reads: "H AR    "
    // So I want to get from the loop my first increment will be H, then empty string, then "A" then "R" etc. 

    // I am doing following 
     for (int j =0; line[j] != '\0';j++) printf("%i : %s",j, &line[j])

   // the results is:

   // 0 : H AR    
   // 1 :  AR 
   // 2 : AR
   // 3 : R
```

Seems like it is going in reverse direction. Can somebody explain to a new C developer why this is occuring, and how I can achieve my objective?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213827/how-to-iterate-over-a-string-in-c)

Comment: No I had already looked it at. But Thanks

Comment: Also the `for` should be closed by `)` instead of `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` prints a null-terminated string, i.e. multiple characters starting from the pointed-to one from the `printf` argument, until a null character is encountered.

If you want to print a single character, you need `%c` and then the corresponding argument to `printf` should be a `int` (or promoted `char`), not a `char*`, so just `line[j]`, not `&line[j]`.

Also, you are meant to check the return value of `fgets` against null, to verify that it succeeded.

Comment: Okay, that is what I am looking for. I know this is not part of the question. But I initially wanted to use these single characters in a `strcmp` function. Do I just use a fprintf to write to a single char variable or is there aanother way doing it

Since I cannot use `line[j]` as an argument to `strcmp`

Comment: @ATK I am not sure what you mean. You don't need `strcmp` to compare individual characters. You can compare them directly with `==`. `strcmp` is needed to compare two null-terminated strings.

Comment: Okay I think I got it. So I can simply do: `line[j] == "!"` to e.g. check if that character has an "!"

Comment: @ATK Not quite, `"!"` is a *string literal*. It is basically a pointer to a null-terminated string. If you want to compare characters, you need a *character literal*, which would be `'!'`.

Comment: Cheers That works. I need to readup how the string/character  works in c. Thanks for help !