# How would I be able to run code for each character in a const char*?

Tags: c, kernel

I am programming a kernel in C for a custom operating system that I'm making and I was wondering how I could loop for every character in a `const char*` and then use `if` operators to identify a character in the `const char*` to run specific code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213827/how-to-iterate-over-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Not exactly

Comment: Could you elaborate? You want to iterate over string, and the referenced question asks about that. You don't ask how to put `if` clause into the each iteration, do you?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do, I have searched this question on google, and have found some answers where the character is stored as `"%c"`, and used inside the `printf` function, but for some reason I can't make an `if` statement to check if the string `"%c"` is equal to a specific character

Comment: Do you know how strings work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I could loop for every character in a `const char*`

Like that:

```c
const char *p;
for (p = str; *p; p++) {
    // ...
}
```

> and then use if operators to identify a character in the `const char*` to run specific code.

Inside your loop:

```c
if (*p == 'x') { // Identify a character
    // Run the specific code here
}
```

Or, if you want to identify a lot of characters:

```c
switch (*p) {
case 'x':
    // Run the specific code here
    break;

case 'y':
    // Run the specific code here
    break;

// ...
}
```