# Struct with Char array is printing garbage... How to fix?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the code below.  When I print out the data I assign to the character arrays in the struct it prints out a bunch of junk unless I add an extra character to the array and put "/0".  The problem with this is later on I need to grab the birth day and month as an integer (4 bytes).  Can anyone tell me how to make it print out the appropriate data?  I need the char array to be the exact size in memory of the size of the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Info
{
        char studentID[6];
        char firstName[5];
        char lastName[4];
        char birthDay[2];
        char birthMonth[2];
        char birthYear[4];
};

void printFunction( struct Info studentInfo );

int main()
{
        struct Info studentInfo = {"999999", "first", "last", "01", "07", "1993"};
        void *baseptr;
        asm("movl %%ebp,%0;":"=r"(baseptr));
        printf("The value of the basepointer main:\n");
        printf("%p\n", baseptr);
        printf("%-15s %s \n", "Student ID:", studentInfo.studentID);
        printf("%-15s %s \n", "First Name:", studentInfo.firstName);
        printf("%-15s %s \n", "Last Name:", studentInfo.lastName);
        printf("%-15s %s \n", "Birth Day:", studentInfo.birthDay);
        printf("%-15s %s \n", "Birth Month:", studentInfo.birthMonth);
        printf("%-15s %s \n", "Birth Year:", studentInfo.birthYear);

        printFunction( studentInfo );
        return 0;
}

void printFunction( struct Info studentInfo )
{
        printf("The value of basepointer printFunction is:\n");
        int *baseptr;
        asm("movl %%ebp,%0;":"=r"(baseptr));
        printf("%p\n", baseptr);
        printf("The value at basepointer address is:\n");
        printf("%p\n", *baseptr);
        printf("%-25s %p \n", "Address of Student ID:", &studentInfo.studentID);
        printf("%-25s %p \n", "Address of First Name:", &studentInfo.firstName);
        printf("%-25s %p \n", "Address of Last Name:", &studentInfo.lastName);
        printf("%-25s %p \n", "Address of Birth Day:", &studentInfo.birthDay);
        printf("%-25s %p \n", "Address of Birth Month:", &studentInfo.birthMonth);
        printf("%-25s %p \n", "Address of Birth Year:", &studentInfo.birthYear);
        printf("%s %x \n", "The address of my birth day and month is at address: ", &studentInfo.birthDay );
        printf("%s \n", "The integer value of my birth day and month is: ");
}
```

Comment: `NUL` terminator. `NUL` terminator. `NUL` terminator. `NUL` terminator. `NUL` terminator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [null terminating a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911089/null-terminating-a-string)

Comment: Your arrays are not big enough.  You need 1 more to store the zero terminator.

Comment: Shouldn't `&studentInfo.studentID` be `&studentInfo->studentID` or `studentInfo.studentID`?

Comment: here is an example fix: printf("%-15s %s \n", "Student ID:", studentInfo.studentID); should be: printf("%-15s %6s \n", "Student ID:", studentInfo.studentID);  where the '6' is the number of characters to print.

Comment: this line: struct Info studentInfo = {"999999", "first", "last", "01", "07", "1993"} will corrupt certain fields, for instance the first field, because the compiler will produce code to copy strings and strings always have a terminating '\0' so the first literal is actually 7 characters long.

Comment: the code can obtain the numeric value of the strings by (when the string is null terminated or has a trailing non numeric character) value = atoi(studentInfo.studentID);

Comment: @Umm no , the original is fine (apart from failure to cast to `(void *)`)

Comment: @user3629249 it will not corrupt fields, a brace-enclosed initializer can never "overflow" like that.  What happens is that the null terminator does not get copied. There is a special case for initializing a char array from a string literal; in other cases where you provide excess initializers it must generate a diagnostic.

Comment: @MattMcNabb OH, youre right; I thought he was trying to print the actual value of the struct field (the char array), not the address of each (didnt see the %p, assumed it was a %s). Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
printf("Birth Day: %c%c \n", studentInfo.birthDay[0], studentInfo.birthDay[1]);
```

Comment: `struct Info studentInfo = {"99999", "firs", "las", {'0','1'}, {'0','7'}, {'1','9','9','3'} };`

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for.

Comment: actually, losing the last chard of each text is NOT a good solution.  Rather make the initializer similar to: struct Info studentInfo = {('9','9','9','9','9','9'), etc };  However, the printf() statements for the values will also need to number of char to print, as in: printf("%-15s %6s \n", "Student ID:", studentInfo.studentID);

Comment: I removed last char for first/last name because the other option was to change the structure. Actually, `char lastName[4];` must be modified to more realistic value - e.g. 20-30 chars instead of 4.

Answer (score 2):

Change your struct definition with sizes sufficient to accommodate the C string termination character: `\0`.

```
struct Info
{
        char studentID[7];
        char firstName[50];
        char lastName[50];
        char birthDay[3];
        char birthMonth[3];
        char birthYear[5];
};
```

Sizes shown are arbitrary in length, but for illustration of your use case, sufficient.

In memory, the member: `studentID[6]` is only created with enough space contain 6 characters, i.e. "999999", but not the ***all important*** *string termination character:* `\0`.  C does not actually have a _string typeP.  Instead, in C, a string is defined as a character array **terminated by a '\0'**

So, studentID[7] would look like this:

```
|'9'|'9'|'9'|'9'|'9'|'9'|0|
```

An important point, when you create a string variable (or a char array) such as:

```
char string[10]  = {0};//space for 10 char
```

then fill it with something like:

```
strcpy(string, "nine char"); //9 spaces used
```

The null terminator is appended as a function of calling `strcpy()`, giving you:

```
|'n'|'i'|'n'|'e'|' '|'c'|'h'|'a'|'r'|0| //9 characters AND a NULL terminator
```

Comment: Suggest reserving  "NULL" for the null pointer `NULL`.  Use `'\0'` or "null character" here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but actually user i486 actually gave me what I needed.  I said in the post that I know you can put /0 but I can't do that for this because I need to use the memory locations in certain ways.

Comment: @KevinZaki - Your mistake is creating memory insufficient for the data you are later attempting to assign.  i.e. `"999999"` will not fit into an array of size 6.  You need 7 `char` spaces to define a string with 6 useable characters and a '\0'.

Comment: @ryyker thanks.  I understand that but this is a school assignment and the next part of the assignment  I can't have char[3] for because I need to pull 4 bytes from memory as an integer which would be char[2] char[2] for birhtMonth and birthDay.  I understand this may not be proper coding but it is what I need to accomplish this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In your structure

```
struct Info
{
        char studentID[6];
        char firstName[5];
        char lastName[4];
        char birthDay[2];
        char birthMonth[2];
        char birthYear[4];
};
```

variables are not having enough memory to store the null terminator. So, printing as string is wrong.

To avoid, always allow one more `char` to store the null terminator. With the same set of initializer,

```
struct Info
{
        char studentID[7];
        char firstName[6];
        char lastName[5];
        char birthDay[3];
        char birthMonth[3];
        char birthYear[5];
};
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the character values in this struct, and you don't want to change the struct to contain null-terminated strings (as you suggest in comments), then you have to tell `printf` a limit on how many characters to print.

Normally `%s` prints until it encounters a null terminator, but your struct does not contain any null terminators, so you have to specify the maximum field width:

```
 printf("%-15s %.6s \n", "Student ID:", studentInfo.studentID);
 //             ^^
```

You can find this value programmatically instead of relying on magic numbers:

```
 printf("%-15s %.*s \n", "Student ID:", 
        (int)(sizeof studentInfo.studentID), studentInfo.studentID);
```

Optionally you could wrap all these lines up in a macro:

```
#define PRINT_ITEM(prompt, field) \
    printf("%-15s %.*s\n", prompt, (int)sizeof(field), field)

PRINT_ITEM("Student ID:", studentInfo.studentID);
PRINT_ITEM("First Name:", studentInfo.firstName);
PRINT_ITEM("Last Name:" , studentInfo.lastName);
// etc.
```

---

NB. The initializers for this struct are correct: in C it is permitted to initialize a char array from a string literal containing exactly as many non-null characters as the size of the array; and that fills the char array with those characters. (This is not permitted in C++).