# understanding pointers and null terminating strings

Tags: c, string

I am fairly novice to c/c++ and I was trying to determine the best way to terminate a string when I ran across [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911089/null-terminating-a-string)

I think I understand whats going on with incrementing a pointer and dereferencing it to a value of '\0'. The problem is, when I do it it doesn't work.

```
    int main()
{
    const char* c = "1234567890";
    char* c1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    strncpy( c1, c, 3 );
    printf( "%s\n",c1 );
    *c1++ = '\0';
    printf( "%s\n",c1 );
}
```

The output is
123
23

It appears that the null value is being dropped at the beginning of the string as opposed to immediately after. Why?

Comment: `*c1++ = '\0';` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Doh! I think I just got it. Since it's a char, not an int, it's only advancing one byte.

Comment: This code exhibits undefined behavior.  The call to `strncpy` copies the first three characters of `c` to `c1`, but it does *not* null-terminate the result.  So the string pointed to by `c1` may or may not be properly terminated.  Don't do it.  In your case, it *happened* to have a null byte where you needed it, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: This code has an error.  Since c is longer than3, stncpy will not add a null terminator.

Comment: `c1++` don't alter a pointer that you (should) `free`.

Comment: Tom, Weather Vane, I think you guys are missing the point. I realize pointers should be free in production code, but since this is a main function which abruptly ends I think it should be ok. Tom, I know the first print statement is not null terminated, but if you read the statement associated with the supplied code you will realize what I am trying to do is determine the best way to do that.

Comment: `c1` is never guaranteed to be null-terminated in either `printf`.  You need to add `c1[3] = '\0';` before or after the call to `strncpy`.  The answer you accepted is blatantly incorrect in its claim that `strncpy` will add a null byte that was not present in the source string.  You just need to read the man page for `strncpy`.  It's also trivial to test, since the `strncpy` call doesn't touch `c1[3]` at all.

Comment: Adding `c1[3] = '\0';` is guaranteed to solve the problem, since either a null byte was copied from `c` earlier in the string, or else it wasn't in which case this fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
*c1++ = '\0';
```

does:

1. Evaluate the variable `c1`. It's a pointer to an allocated block of 4 bytes.
2. De-reference the pointer with `*`, which is now the first byte pointed to by `c1`.
3. Assign the value `'\0'` to that byte, overwriting the `'1'` that was there.
4. Add 1 to `c1`. Now it points to the second byte of those 4 you allocated, which contains a `'2'`.

Later, when you print `c1` as a string, it starts at the `2` where you left it, and ends at the terminating `'\0'` that just happened to be in the last byte of your allocated region that never got set.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `strncpy` does *not* insert a terminating null byte unless it was copied from the original string.  The call to `strncpy` will not write more than 3 bytes of `c1`.  The code posted by OP exhibits *undefined behavior*, since there is no guarantee that `c1` is properly terminated.  Look at the man page for `strncpy`.

Comment: Hmm. I thought strncpy did add the zero. I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: It's very clear from the man page.  If you want to test it, add `c1[3] = 'x';` before the call to `strncpy`.  You will see the `x` appear in the output, which contradicts your claim.