# program does not read string with the defined length in fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, stdio

I found when I use the `fgets` function like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    fgets(str, 5, stdin);

    printf("%s", str);
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

If I input a `123456789`, it will output a `1234`. That's 4 characters - not the 5 I have defined in the function. What is happening to the fifth character?

edit: title updated

Comment: fifth character is null character. strings end with null termination in C language

Comment: @saygins sorry for discarding your edit, but I had a concurrent substantial edit in the works at the same time. and NULL (the preprocessor macro for the null pointer) is not the same as NUL (the null character): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911089/null-terminating-a-string

Comment: see [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (_Reads at most **count - 1** characters from the given file stream_)

Answer (score 0):

that's because since C-strings are NUL terminated, `fgets` takes the string terminator (`\0`) into account, so if you pass a 5-char buffer, it is safe.

In your code, you should do:

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```

since `str` is an array with known size.